# State is undefined from the main context of useContext

Tags: reactjs

First of all im brasilian. So im sorry for my english. ive studying the useContext hook about a week. There are a lot diferent ways in the internet to implement it. I want to know what im thinking wrong. Here is the code. There are 3 files to show me what to do. I wanna get the state user and show in the App component. Thanks a lot.

```
import { useState, createContext } from "react";
import RecebeContexto from "../components/RecebeContexto";

export const UserContext = createContext();

function Contexto() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState("Jesse Hall");
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
        <h1>{`Hello ${user}!`}</h1>
        <RecebeContexto user={user} />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  }

export default Contexto
```

This is the main context

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import Contexto from "../contexto/Contexto";
import { UserContext } from "../contexto/Contexto";

function RecebeContexto() {
    const user = useContext( UserContext );
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Component 5</h1>
        <h2>{`Hello ${user} again!`}</h2>
      </>
    );
}
export default RecebeContexto
```

this file recieves the context state

Answer (score 1):

While getting a data from context, You have to use 'object destructing'. So you have to get the user from `UserContext` like below,

```
const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

RecebeContexto Shouldn't have the user passed down since you will get it from the context.

The line

```
<RecebeContexto user={user} />
```

Should be:

```
<RecebeContexto />
```

### Everything is working; check your node_modules

I tried your code:

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
export const UserContext = createContext();

function RecebeContexto() {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component 5</h1>
      <h2>{`Hello ${user} again!`}</h2>
    </>
  );
}

function Contexto() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("Jesse Hall");
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
      <h1>{`Hello ${user}!`}</h1>
      <RecebeContexto user={user} />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default Contexto;
```

And everything is working. What leads me to think that something might be wrong with your dependencies?

Try to run:

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install && npm run start
```

Let me know if it helped.